# pass a backend from backend map to haproxy nbsrv

Tags: haproxy

Can someone advise what I have to change in the nbsrv expression in order to make it work:

```
frontend webfarm
    bind 11.22.33.44:80
    ...
    acl MAIN_not_enough_capacity nbsrv([%[req.hdr(host),lower,map(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,bk_default)]]) eq 0

    http-request redirect code 301 location http://global-swajm.example.com if MAIN_not_enough_capacity

    use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,bk_default)]
```

The idea is according to the host in the header to get the right backend name from the map file.
If there are no available servers in this backend the request will be redirected to another haproxy (in another DC).

use_backend is working perfectly:

```
use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,bk_default)]
```

but I don't know how to modify the expression for nbsrv in order to pass the backend name:

```
nbsrv([%[req.hdr(host),lower,map(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,bk_default)]])
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

just chiming in after having struggled with the same

Use

```
acl MAIN_not_enough_capacity req.hdr(host),lower,map(/etc/haproxy/backend.map,bk_default),nbsrv eq 0
```

instead

Comment: hey @rvs, can you maybe add some more information on what the solution does/how it works?